How do I retrieve instruction data from a transaction in python?
hey noob here with Solana so apologies in advanced!
I am using solders and Solana-py to write a program that stores data in a transaction. Specifically, it will store it in the instruction data attribute of the message class. For testing, I am using devnet, and the program uses base64 for encoding and decoding, though I have tried base58. I have successfully stored it. But I have issues retrieving it. There wasn't a question that specifically answered this, so I thought I'd ask.
Here is the code snippet:
"""
'async def retrieve_from_solana(index_signature):
async with AsyncClient("https://api.devnet.solana.com") as client:
try:
logging.info(f"Starting retrieval for signature: {index_signature}")
signature = Signature.from_string(index_signature)
        tx_response = await client.get_transaction(
            tx_sig=signature,
            encoding="base64",
            commitment=Confirmed,
            max_supported_transaction_version=None
        )
        
        if tx_response is None or tx_response.value is None:
            logging.error(f"Transaction not found for signature: {index_signature}")
            return None
        
        transaction = tx_response.value
        logging.info(f"Retrieved transaction type: {type(transaction)}")
        
        if isinstance(transaction, EncodedConfirmedTransactionWithStatusMeta):
            encoded_tx = transaction.transaction.transaction
        elif hasattr(transaction, 'transaction') and isinstance(transaction.transaction, VersionedTransaction):
            # Handle VersionedTransaction
            encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(transaction.transaction.serialize()).decode('ascii')
        else:
            logging.error(f"Unexpected transaction type: {type(transaction)}")
            return None
        
        # Decode the base64 transaction data
        decoded_tx = base64.b64decode(encoded_tx)
        
        # Rest of the function remains the same...
        
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected error in retrieve_from_solana: {str(e)}", exc_info=True)
        return None

"""
Here is the error:
"""'
retrieve_from_solana
decoded_tx = base64.b64decode(encoded_tx)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/base64.py", line 83, in b64decode
s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/base64.py", line 45, in _bytes_from_decode_data
raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'VersionedTransaction'
'"""
There may be an issue with the legacy transaction types, specifically get_transaction(). I've tried versionedtransaction, encodedtransactionwithstatusmeta, and encodedconfirmedtransactionwithstatusmeta. I've reviewed the docs and several repos but don't know where I am going wrong. Here are my sources:
https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/rpc/api/#solana.rpc.api.Client.get_transaction
https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/main/python/solders/transaction_status.pyi
appreciate any help!

You're very close! You need to dig into the transaction that you receive from get_transaction to get at the instruction data bytes. I used https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4z8tLwYsFznkggvh5teDpMcA1aZARKHWMidcGZ4KtJpp87ZvLM97ZQ1uJ65P6Qofns7EBkTza3bgKoxWBZpicX7H?cluster=devnet as a random example, and here's what I needed to do to get instruction data:
        transaction = tx_response.value
        if isinstance(transaction, EncodedConfirmedTransactionWithStatusMeta):
            encoded_tx = transaction.transaction.transaction
        elif hasattr(transaction, 'transaction') and isinstance(transaction.transaction, VersionedTransaction):
            # Not sure what to do here!
            encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(transaction.transaction.serialize()).decode('ascii')
        else:
            logging.error(f"Unexpected transaction type: {type(transaction)}")
            return None
        print(encoded_tx.message.instructions[0].data)

get_transaction does some of the work for you already, so you can just reach into the structure that it returns.
